# How to use Theories and Parameterized unit tests runners together?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to use multiple setup scenarious in one unit tests class. Also I need to use many cases for testing methods. As for me, it is most natural to use **Parametrized** and **Theories** runners together for something like follow:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedTheories.class)
public class Tests {

    Setup o;

    @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
    public static Iterable<Object> data() {
        return asList(new Object[][]{
                        asArray("First", Tests::setup1),
                        asArray("Second",Tests::setup2),
                     });

    public Tests(String name, Setuper setuper) {
         Setup o = setuper.setup();
    }

    @Theory
    public void AddSevenTest(
          @TestedOn(ints = {0, 5, 10})int x){

        o.implementation.addSevenAnd(x);
        verify(o.storageMock).save(x + 7);
    }

    static Setup setup1(){
         // ...
    }

    static Setup setup2(){
         // ...
    }

    interface Setuper {
        Setup setup();
    }

    static class Setup {
        IStorage storageMock;
        ITesting implementation;
    }
}
```

I found nothing for just use. Is anything that can help me exists? What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible to implement by just using existing JUnit tools(classes), but by extending one of classes from hierarchy of JUnit Runner-s.

Also, this problem can be solved by other simple following way:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class BaseTests {

    protected Setup o;

    @Before
    public void setUp();

    @Theory
    public void AddSevenTest(
         @TestedOn(ints = {0, 5, 10})int x){

         o.implementation.addSevenAnd(x);
         verify(o.storageMock).save(x + 7);
    }

    static class Setup {
         IStorage storageMock;
         ITesting implementation;
    }
}

public class Tests1 extends BaseTests {
    @Ovveride @Before
    public void setUp() {
         // ...
    }
}

public class Tests2 extends BaseTests {
    @Ovveride @Before
    public void setUp() {
         // ...
    }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    Tests1.class,
    Tests2.class
})

public class Tests {   
}
```